# How do I use multiple facebook bundle ids with one app?

Tags: ios, facebook

I would like to use the facebook sdk in an ios library, and then use my library to provide a one click login experience for apps which use my library.

But to do this it looks like I need to register each bundle id for each app which uses my library to my facebook app.

Is there a way to get around this bundle id checking restriction?

Answer (score 0):

[First link here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting/) shows that you can add a URL scheme suffix to distinguish between multiple iOS apps and add all of their bundle IDs to the Facebook app.